# Special characters in C# public comments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xml-comments

I have a library for which I have to create the XML documentation. Therefore, for all public methods and properties I inserted XML comments. Unfortunately, for some comments I have to insert the special character < or > to describe the return type (a List). The compiler continues to issue a warning for invalid character and indicates the character `<`.
How do I persuade the compiler to accept this character without warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I persuade the compiler to accept this character without warnings?

You don't. You have to use the equivalent XML entity (`&lt;`)

Note that if you use the `<see cref="..." />` element, you can specify the type like this:

```
<see cref="List{T}"/>
```